# Refactor this method to reduce its Cognitive Complexity , Simplificar codigo (en equals)

Tags: java, sonar, complejidad

estoy usando sonarQube para analizar mi codigo y me genera errores Criticos cuando la Cognitive Complexity supera 15. Esto pasa sobre todo en los equals , que comprueban muchas cosas de la clase.

Varias preguntas:

1. Esto , a priori , seria equivalente (pero mejor a la hora de bajar la complejidad ),¿ no ?

Contexto

```
 public boolean equals(Object obj){EventDateField other = (EventDateField) obj};
```

**+2 (incl 1 for nesting) to Cognitive Complexity**

```
   if (fieldValues == null)
{
  if (other.fieldValues != null)
    return false;
}
else if (!fieldValues.equals(other.fieldValues))
  return false;
```

**+1 to Cognitive Complexity**

```
    if (fieldValues == null && other.fieldValues != null)
{
    return false;
}
else if (!fieldValues.equals(other.fieldValues))
  return false;
```

2. ¿ Maneras correctas de bajar la Cognitive Complexity ( sin modificar la logica del problema , o revisarla ) ?

Codigo completo del equals:

```
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
  {
    if (this == obj)
      return true;
    if (obj == null)
      return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
      return false;
    EventDateField other = (EventDateField) obj;
    if (child != other.child)
      return false;
    if (fieldName == null)
    {
      if (other.fieldName != null)
        return false;
    }
    else if (!fieldName.equals(other.fieldName))
      return false;
    if (fieldTag == null)
    {
      if (other.fieldTag != null)
        return false;
    }
    else if (!fieldTag.equals(other.fieldTag))
      return false;
    if (operations == null)
    {
      if (other.operations != null)
        return false;
    }
    else if (!operations.equals(other.operations))
      return false;
    return true;
  }
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: fieldValues y other.fieldValues son diferentes valores? o asignas fieldValues a partir del valor de other.fieldValues ?

Comment: Perdona , que no lo he puesto en contexto , fieldValues es el atributo de la Clase y other es el objeto que se le pasa , es un metodo equals .

Comment: La única forma para bajar el Cognitive Complexity es o minimizar la cantidad de if anidados o partir la lógica en métodos que realicen grupos de validaciones, si pudiese colocar un método completo de validación serviría para ver que se puede rescribir o como seccionar la lógica para bajar el nivel.

Comment: Un seg y lo edito. @RobertoEMoran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno como es un poco difícil determinar el contexto y el tipo de datos de los campos  como determinar si todas las comparaciones utilizadas son correctas, al menos para bajar el nivel de método, bastaría con realizar unos cambios al if final:

Estos cambios son equivalentes a lo que ya tienes,  porque el ‘if (other.operations != null)’ se puede simplificar haciendo un ‘return’ directo de la comparación al igual, y con el `return` final y el `else if (!operations.equals(other.operations))` se puede simplificar  realizando una unión.

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    EventDateField other = (EventDateField) obj;
    if (child != other.child)
        return false;
    if (fieldName == null)
    {
        if (other.fieldName != null)
            return false;
    }
    else if (!fieldName.equals(other.fieldName))
        return false;
    if (fieldTag == null)
    {
        if (other.fieldTag != null)
            return false;
    }
    else if (!fieldTag.equals(other.fieldTag))
        return false;
    if (operations == null)
    {
        return other.operations == null;
    }
    else
        return operations.equals(other.operations);
}
```

Lo pase por mi sonarQube y el Cognitive Complexity 15 ya no marca el metodo.